# asp querystring between two number

Tags: asp-classic, query-string, between

I wonder if the below use of between in the link is correct considering the scenario below

main.asp page

```
<a href="http://details.asp?number between 01 and 08>)
 click here for number between 1 and 8
</a>
```

This is query in access

```
select * from table
where right("000" & number,2) between [enter start number] and [enter end number]
```

This is the Table in access

```
number| field1| field2| field3
1     | xys   | abc   | at
2      |sdfd  | dfasd | dd
3     | sdfd  | ddd    | dd
```

The below is details.asp code

```
<html>
<body>

<%
Dim numCategoryID
numCategoryID = Request.Querystring("number")

set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "query"

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
strQuery = "queryname '" & numCategoryID & "'"
rs.Open strQuery, conn
%>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if there is any mistake in the above codes. Actually when I click on the link main.asp, it should open the query where number between 1 and 8.

This is my third try to get output between two numbers when user enters the two numbers in form

```
<%
dim startnumber, endnumber
startnumber = Request.form("number")
endnumber = Request.form("number")
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "connection"

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
strQuery = "SELECT * from query " _
& "where number between" & startnumber_
& "& endnumber;
rs.Open strQuery, conn
%>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: Is this your actual code or have you edited it? `strQuery = "queryname '" & numCategoryID & "'" ` isn't going to be a valid SQL query.

Comment: How this works will depend on the data types of your DB columns. You may need to cast values as string to pad them with zeroes and back to integers for comparison. Also, you should never accept client-side values without sanitizing them to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: this is my actual code but i just changed queryname, tablename and field name in this example....the field "number" is text data type in access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a reworked version with some advise, it would surprise me if it works right a way, it's just ot give you an idea, also the part about passing through a number and selection from the db is probably different from what you want, anyway check your requested parameter and only show the rest if the parameters are there with correct values, otherwise show a message

```
'no sql parts in your url, just parameters with a value
'this just indicates you want the numbers between 1 and 8, 
'doesn't select a specific number, 
'then you need eg a form with an input box in your main.asp page

'main.asp
<a href="http://details.asp?number=true>) 
 click here for number between 1 and 8 
</a> 

'details.asp
'best not mix html with code, using one code block here
w "<html>"
w "  <body>"
dim number, conn, rs, connectionstring, strQuery
number = Request.Querystring("number")
if number then
  'adapt the connectionstring for other versions of access and/or files
  connectionString = "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("\mydb.mdb") & ";DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
  set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
  conn.open ConnectionString
  'best to not be dependent on a query, put your sql here
  'no need for an empty recordset first
  strQuery = "select * from table where number between 1 and 8;"
  set rs = conn.execute(strQuery)

  w "      <table border='1' width='100%'>"
  w "        <tr>"
  for each x in rs.Fields
    w "        <th>" & x.name & "</th>"
  next 
  w "        </tr>"
  do until rs.EOF
    w "      <tr>"
    for each x in rs.Fields
      w "      <td>" & x.value & "</td>"
    next 
    rs.MoveNext
    w "      </tr>"
  loop

  rs.close 
  conn.close
  set conn = nothing 'close and cleanup your connection properly

  w "    </table>"
else
  w "No parameter number found"
end if
w "  </body>"
w "</html>"
'--- ---'
sub w (text)
  response.write(text) & VbCrLf
end sub
%>
```

to test your database connection make an asp like this

```
<%
on error resume next
connectionString = "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("\mydb.mdb") & ";DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
      set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
      conn.open ConnectionString
if err.number <> 0 then
  response.write err.description
else
  response.write "Connection was succesfull.."
end if
%>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried your code  but I get error "NO Parameter Number Found".
I'm not sure if it is because the number date/type format is text.

Comment: This also doesn't work..
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e10'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. 
please note i removed your connectionstring line and just write as below
  
  
    
    if number then
    set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    conn.open ODBConnectionname

Comment: I don't know asp very well, but it seems to me that this piece code may have a bug:

Can you try to move "if number then" to the section following this line:  "set rs = conn.execute(strQuery)" ?  Logically, the IF Number fails if the query does not return a value.  I'm reading the above as the test occurs before the connection to the database is made and any results can be returned, which would always return a False, and drop you to the ELSE condition producing the error:  w "No parameter number found"

Comment: @TexasTubbs, the If number checks if a parameters number is passed to the page, and if the page is called with "details.asp?number=true" it is But as i stated earlier it is uncertain what the OP wants to pass as a parameter and what to do with it, obviously this needs some tailoring

Comment: @user1449596 first check out what your connection string needs to be, it depends on which system, which version etc so just make an asp which opens a connection and display a message if succesfull, open the page in a browser with a decent debugger like firebug in firefox so that you see errors if they happen, i'll add it to the answer

Comment: @Peter, Thanks for the explanation!  it makes a lot more sense.  As stated before, I don't fully understand ASP, but I do understand a little more clearly what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Peter
wow! finally,   after a long time, I can see it displays the output using your code...i'm excited..
But one thing I'm looking for here...instead of writing `"between 1 and 8" or "between 9 to 15"` in different pages..`i'm looking for a page with two text box where user enter two number and display the output`

Comment: More information why it didn't work before - I set paramatized query in access and tried to display using your code which didn't work..now I just made it a simple query which displays complete output and used your code in asp..it worked fine..

Comment: @Peter...I tried myself a code which should display output when user enters in two text boxes the startnumber and endnumber. But it doesn't work. Can you please assist with this? I updated this in my original question.

Comment: as before, isolate the code you have problems with and try it out separately. You get start and end both from the same field, Request.form("number"), that should be number1 and number2 and the fields in your form should be named like that

Comment: This is simply amazing - `Request.form("number"), that should be number1 and number2 and the fields in your form should be named like that` . I corrected it and it works fine with my code...Thank you very much